# Calculate Day Number Column in Relation to Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to get the number of day for StartDate in relation to the EndDate as a column in a temp table. So 12/16 would be day one and 12/17 would be day two etc.

Current:

| ID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2020/12/16 | 2020/12/18 |
| 02 | 2020/12/17 | 2020/12/18 |
| 03 | 2020/12/18 | 2020/12/18 |

Needed Result:

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | Day in Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2020/12/16 | 2020/12/18 | 1 |
| 02 | 2020/12/17 | 2020/12/18 | 2 |
| 03 | 2020/12/18 | 2020/12/18 | 3 |

Is it possible to do in SQL Server?

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: So far I have tried using datediff but I'm not necessarily looking for the duration. I have also tried to partition using row number but there are instances where there might be two rows with the same startdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, min(startdate) over (partition by enddate), startdate) + 1
from t;
```

This returns the difference between the start date on the current row and the earliest start date associated with that end date.